# Semantic Circles

Tags: word, visual

Rotate the annuli to align the letters of related words.

The first puzzle:

[image]

The second puzzle:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First puzzle gives:

> Bug, Fly, Bee, Ant

Second puzzle gives:

> Toast, Broil, Crock, Stove, Whisk, Mixer, Spoon, Blend, Steam, Forks

I found the solution to the second puzzle by

> looking at the X and the V. I looked at word starts that had an X as third letter (fox, fix, tox, mix, box) where the other word starts made sense as well. The V probably had an E afterwards which gave a fixed rotation between the inner two rings. From there I noticed "stove" which gave the solution.